# Basic PHP Login issues, PDO.

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on a basic session based login system, however running into some issues. I've been messing with it for about an hour now, and it's probably something small that I've overlooked, basically the passwords aren't matching, even though they should be.

**Here's my registration code:**

```
function populateTables($user, $pass, $email) {
    include 'connection.php';
    $salt = generateSalt(40);
    $hash = md5(md5($salt) . md5($pass));
    $statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `".$sqlDatabase."`.`login` (`username`, `password`, `salt`, `email`) VALUES (:user, :pass, :salt, :email)");
    $statement->bindParam(":user", $user);
    $statement->bindParam(":pass", $hash);
    $statement->bindParam(":salt", $salt);
    $statement->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

**Here's my login code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'])) {
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `".$sqlDatabase."`.`login` WHERE `username`=:name");
    $statement->bindParam(":name", $_POST['user']);
    $statement->execute();
    if($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        $hash = md5(md5($row['salt']).md5($_POST['pass']));
        if($hash == $row['password']) {
            echo "Success";
        } else {
            header('Location: index.php?action=2'); // Invalid login
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

My table structure uses a VarChar(40) for the salt and the password, and the salt is 40 characters long, if you're interested in seeing the generateSalt method, it's below:

**Generate salt code:**

```
function generateSalt($length) {
    $characters = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789";
    $randomizer = strlen($characters);
    $resultsalt = "";
    for($index = 0; $index < $randomizer; $index++) {
        $resultsalt .= $characters[rand(0, ($randomizer - 1))];
    }
    return $resultsalt;
}
```

It's strange I'm running into this, and the fact it's bee a brick wall- I completed the entire auto-installer without problems, database population, file generation, etc for this little project I'm working on, but I can't verify the username/password....

This is upsetting me, because I work with logins almost every day.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, not related to the bug, what's the purpose of $length in generateSalt?

Comment: @Brendan - This method is used for more than just the login, it's used to generate table tokens, custom transaction ids (from the IPN script) and in a few other places.

Comment: @Christian.tucker The point Brendan was making is that you never use the `$length` variable. You use `strlen($characters)` instead, so the `40` part in `generateSalt(40)` makes no sense. It could be `generateSalt(1337)` and nothing would change.

Comment: Actually, this was the answer to the question. I used the $randomizer variable instead of the $length variable here, so the salt being generated was 62 characters long, instead of 40 ($length) thus it was being truncated in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Am not able to see any issues on the code. But what if the password submitted contains extra spaces? The `md5()` would be different isn't it?

ie, say I entered the passsword as `akhilesh`, the md5 generated for this string would be `cea5d966c02da451458981edc480d135`. Instead of that, I accidentally included an extra space at the end like `akhilesh`(note the space at the end) and the md5 generated might be `4ae99825292c6b415116b31c68ddeb40`. So, both are different. Thereby your `$hash` would be different too!

So, try trimming the string using `trim()` function on that `$_POST['pass']` before applying the `md5()` and see if it works.

BTW, if you want to see it live, have a look at this: http://codepad.org/cqfksBH8

Hope my suggestion would help. If you still have issues, try debugging the code by checking the hash values(both from db and user submitted) and verify whether they are same, etc.